# How to get date in days only Java?

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the date in java in days only? For instance Jan 1 would equal 1 and Feb 1 would equal 32? Instead of the standard time format yyyy/mm/dd?
Perhaps by editing the date formater somehow:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
```

Comment: Use `Day-of-year`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getDayOfYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfYear--):

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfYear());
```

> Returns: the day-of-year, from 1 to 365, or 366 in a leap year

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

Answer (score 0):

int day = LocalDate.getDayOfYear();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      Date dt1=format1.parse(pass your date);
      DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
      String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
```